# How to pass date objects as request parameters through Spring MockMvc

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a unit test that uses Spring's MockMvc testing framework to hit a REST endpoint. The rest endpoint requires that two string path variables be sent, along with two `java.util.Date` objects which are passed as **@RequestParameters**. When I run the test, it fails because the Date objects are either not present, or can't be serialized from a string JSON representation to a Date object. For the record, execution fails before hitting the end point listed in the `.perform()`, so this problem is not coming from the code being tested. It's coming from the test.

Here's my test:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetHitsForCell() {
    String categoryName = "categoryName";

    try {

        String startDateJson = gson.toJson(new Date());
        String endDateJson = gson.toJson(new Date());
        ResultActions ra = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/rest/tickets/" + ticketName + "/" + categoryName).requestAttr("startDate", new Date())
                .requestAttr("endDate", new Date()).with(user(user)));
        MvcResult aResult = ra.andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = aResult.getResponse();

        assertTrue(response.getContentType().equals("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        assertTrue(gson.fromJson(response.getContentAsString(), PaginatedResults.class) instanceof PaginatedResults);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The endpoint looks like this:

```
/rest/ticket/{ticketName}/{categoryName}?startDate=2015-07-21T14%3A26%3A51.972-0400&endDate=2015-08-04T14%3A26%3A51.972-0400
```

This is the exception that the MockMvc throws:

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Date parameter 'startDate' is not present

My test application context looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <import resource="classpath:propertiesPlaceholder.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:cache.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:mongo-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:securityContext.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:service-commons.xml" />

    <import resource="classpath:mockUserProviderContext.xml" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <!-- Use the Jackson mapper defined above to serialize dates appropriately -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <!-- Jackson Mapper -->
    <bean name="jacksonObjectMapper"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="featuresToDisable">
            <array>
                <util:constant
                    static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS" />
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- SimpleDateFormat for Jackson to use for formatting Date objects -->
    <bean id="standardDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="ticketApp" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="mongodb.dao.TicketDao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="service.commons.*" />

</beans>
```

What can I do to correctly pass these Date objects to the above rest endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a couple of things were wrong here:

I didn't need to use the .requestAttr() calls for the date objects. I simply added string representations of the dates to the call as query parameters like so:

```
private String end = "2015-12-31T23:59:59.999Z";
private String start = "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";

ResultActions ra = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/rest/hits/" + modelId + "/0" + "?startDate=" + start + "&endDate=" + end).with(user(user)));
```

Also, passing in Date objects caused an issue because their format of the string representation was wrong. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer, but just for future someone's search.

In order to solve this problem you can use `get(URL).param` instead:

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/rest/tickets/" + ticketName + "/" + categoryName).param("startDate", new Date())
            .param("endDate", new Date()).with(user(user)));
```

Comment: This won't compile. There is not param() method that takes String and Date parameters. Has to be formatted as a String first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MockMVC is stupid.
This doesn't work

```
 this.mockMvc.perform(get()
                .queryParam("startDate","2011-01-01")
                .queryParam("endDate", "2000-11-31")
```

You have to hardCode the Date DIRECTLY in URL, like so:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder = get(CONFIRMATION_API_GET+"?startDate=2019-09-12&endDate=2019-10-13");
```